# Command dnx web not working on mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, yo, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to run asp.net on mac. I installed everything properly but when I run the command "`dnx web`" it crashes.

> This is my project.json file:

```
 {
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "compilationOptions": {
     "emitEntryPoint": true
   },
   "tooling": {
     "defaultNamespace": "MyWebApp"
   },

   "dependencies": {
     "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
     // Dependencies deleted for brevity.
     "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
   },

   "commands": {
     "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
     "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
   },

   // Markup deleted for brevity.

   "scripts": {
     "prepublish": [
       "npm install",
       "bower install",
       "gulp clean",
       "gulp min"
     ]
   }
```

}
that is the log:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this on my Mac yesterday with no issues. Can you run a "dnvm list" command to ensure that the proper DNX is there?

Did you do a "dnu restore" as well?

Also, can you summarize the steps that you followed to get where you are now? When I first tried it, I missed a step somewhere and it didn't work for me. Then I re-read the steps and tried again, then it worked for me.

I also realized that my port number was different from the one in the documentation so the browser couldn't find my web app the first time I had everything done right. I looked at the terminal to determine the correct port number, then got it to work in my browser.

Comment: usual steps, install asp, visual studio code, node, yeoman. Then, create a project with yo aspnet command, and then run dun restore, and dmx web

Comment: could you tell me more about this port number issue

Comment: Re: port number, you know how your web app runs locally on a URL like http://localhost:12345? The documentation uses an example of port number 5000. When I ran the commands in the terminal, the success message mentions the port that it was actually running on. So that's the port number I used to get it to show up in the browser.

Comment: FYI, the documentation I'm referring to is at: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

Comment: I fixed the problem, it turned out that I did not update something properly. So, I updated dnvm and now it is working

Comment: That's great to hear! :)